# a few query with one sql connection

Tags: c#

```
private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=MAZI-PC\\PROJECTACC;Initial Catalog=programDB;Integrated Security=True");
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select label_sh from label_text where label_form='2' and label_form_labelID='1'", conn);
    conn.Open();
    label1.Text = cmd.ExecuteReader().ToString();
    conn.Close();

    SqlConnection conn1 = new SqlConnection("Data Source=MAZI-PC\\PROJECTACC;Initial Catalog=programDB;Integrated Security=True");
    SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand("select label_sh from label_text where label_form='2' and label_form_labelID='2'", conn1);
    conn1.Open();
    label2.Text = cmd1.ExecuteReader().ToString();
    conn1.Close();

    SqlConnection conn2 = new SqlConnection("Data Source=MAZI-PC\\PROJECTACC;Initial Catalog=programDB;Integrated Security=True");
    SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand("select label_sh from label_text where label_form='2' and label_form_labelID='3'", conn2);
    conn2.Open();
    label3.Text = cmd2.ExecuteReader().ToString();
    conn2.Close();
}
```

I fetch the label texts from database. But in every fetching operation I open a connection in order to write a query. This is my first project in C#. How can I write a few query without opening many connections ? can anyone help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. use `using-statement` to ensure that a connecion gets closed even in case of exception. You should always use it when a class implements `IDisposable`.
2. With [`Connection-Pooling`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8xx3tyca.aspx) you're not always opening and closing connections when you call `con.Open()` or `con.Close()`. Actually `Close` just makes the connection reusable, otherwise it would be marked as "in use". So it's good practise to close connections as soon as possible.

You could use a `DataAdapter` to fill a `DataTable`  with one query. Then you would have all three records and could take what you need:

```
using (var conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=MAZI-PC\\PROJECTACC;Initial Catalog=programDB;Integrated Security=True"))
{
    var sql = "select label_sh from label_text where label_form_labelID IN('1','2','3') and label_form='2'";
    using (var da = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, conn))
    {
        da.Fill(table); // you don't need to open a connection when using a DataAdapter
    }
}

label1.Text = table.AsEnumerable()
                   .Single(r => r.Field<int>("label_form_labelID") == 1)
                   .Field<String>("label_sh");
label2.Text = table.AsEnumerable()
                   .Single(r => r.Field<int>("label_form_labelID") == 2)
                   .Field<String>("label_sh");
label3.Text = table.AsEnumerable()
                  .Single(r => r.Field<int>("label_form_labelID") == 3)
                  .Field<String>("label_sh");
```

Note that you need to add `using System.Linq;` for `Linq-To-DataTable`.

Answer (score 2):

There's no need to close the connection each time. You can even reuse the SqlCommand variable in your example.

```
private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=MAZI-PC\\PROJECTACC;Initial Catalog=programDB;Integrated Security=True");

            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select label_sh from label_text where label_form='2' and label_form_labelID='1'", conn);
            conn.Open();
            label1.Text = cmd.ExecuteReader().ToString();

            cmd.CommandText ="select label_sh from label_text where label_form='2' and label_form_labelID='2'";
            label2.Text = cmd.ExecuteReader().ToString();

            cmd.CommandText = "select label_sh from label_text where label_form='2' and label_form_labelID='3'"
            label3.Text = cmd.ExecuteReader().ToString();

            conn.Close();
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can reuse your `SqlConnection` for all the `SqlCommand` objects and after your are finished you can close the `SqlConnection`:

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=MAZI-PC\\PROJECTACC;Initial Catalog=programDB;Integrated Security=True");
conn.Open();

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select label_sh from label_text where label_form='2' and label_form_labelID='1'", conn);    
label1.Text = cmd.ExecuteReader().ToString();

SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand("select label_sh from label_text where label_form='2' and label_form_labelID='2'", conn);    
label2.Text = cmd1.ExecuteReader().ToString();  


SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand("select label_sh from label_text where label_form='2' and label_form_labelID='3'", conn);   
label3.Text = cmd2.ExecuteReader().ToString();

conn.Close();
```

But it's even better for the performance to create one SQL query to retrieve your labels.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I suggest you  to create only one connection to de DB

```
 SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=MAZI-PC\\PROJECTACC;Initial Catalog=programDB;Integrated Security=True");
```

and then you can use SQL IN Operator to make only one query  like this

```
select label_sh 
from label_text 
where label_form='2' and label_form_labelID IN ('1','2','3')
```

[SQL IN Operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177682.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Just showing another method which only require a single connection, a single command and a single data reader.

While Tim Schmelter approach is the most effective in your case, this a demo of the `NextResult` method of a `DataReader`.

Notice how the sql query in the `SqlCommand` included 3 sub queries separated by a semicolon. Whenever you call `NextResult`, you move to the next query.

```
using (var connection = new SqlConnection("Data Source=MAZI-PC\\PROJECTACC;Initial Catalog=programDB;Integrated Security=True"))
using (var command = new SqlCommand(
@"select label_sh from label_text where label_form='2' and label_form_labelID='1';
select label_sh from label_text where label_form='2' and label_form_labelID='2';
select label_sh from label_text where label_form='2' and label_form_labelID='3'", connection))
using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
{
    var label1 = reader["label_sh"];

    reader.NextResult();

    var label2 = reader["label_sh"];

    reader.NextResult();

    var label3 = reader["label_sh"];
}
```